# Azure DevOps self check out task issue. (pointing to commit instead of branch)

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm facing a Detached head branch issue while deploying API using Azure DevOps. The self-checkout task is pointing to commit instead of branch. The same template pipeline we are using for all of our deployments and it is working fine.

I tried the same template pipeline for other deployments and it was working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And why the Mule tag? Nothing you mentioned is related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same situation.

[image]

The cause of the issue could be related to the fetch depth of the Pipeline repo.

By default, the Shallow fetch of the pipeline repo is 1 by default.

You can try to set the **fetchDepth** to **0** in YAML Pipeline.

For example:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
```

Or you can navigate to **YAML Pipeline -> ... -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get sources -> Shallow fetch**.  You can unselect the option.

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help. Could you please help me to understand why this issue happened only for my new  deployment, though my all deployments are happening without any issue and using the same pipeline. I m not a DevOps guy soo was asking. Appreciate your help.!!!